# load jquery with parmeters

Tags: php, ajax, load

I want to change my inner div

```
<div class="progress" id="divpercent">
    <div  class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $percent ?>" >
        <?php echo $percent ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the code:

```
var percent= ariza/need2pack ;
$("#divpercent").load("percent.php", {
    percent1:percent
});
```

and this is "percent.php":

```
<?php
$percent = $_GET['percent1'];
?>

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" 
aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $percent ?>" >
    <?php echo $percent ?> 
</div>
```

the div doesnt load to the main page
what an I doing worng ?

Comment: What's the problem with you?

Comment: the div doesnt load to the main page

Comment: It might be cached by the broswer,you can add a timestamp to the url

Answer (score 0):

found the problem
used GET 
need to use POST
on the new php page